# procedure update query optimization in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I have the following procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `task_51_proce`()
BEGIN

  DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE v_pkid INTEGER;
  DECLARE v_mine INTEGER;
  DECLARE v_date DATETIME;
  DECLARE v_lat INTEGER;
  DECLARE v_lng INTEGER;

DECLARE weather_cursor CURSOR FOR select pkid, mine_id, accident_dt, lat, lng
                              from mytable;


-- declare NOT FOUND handler
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;
OPEN weather_cursor;

get_update: LOOP

    FETCH weather_cursor INTO v_pkid, v_mine, v_date, v_lat, v_lng;

    IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
        LEAVE get_update;
    END IF;

    UPDATE mytable mt
    INNER JOIN myvalues mv
    ON STR_TO_DATE(mv.Date, '%m/%d/%Y') = mt.accident_dt
    SET mt.tmax = mv.tmax, mt.tmin = mv.tmin, mt.dayl= mv.dayl ,
    mt.prcp = mv.prcp , mt.srad = mv.srad, mt.swe=mv.swe, mt.vp=mv.vp
    WHERE mv.Longitude_MAX >= v_lng and 
                      mv.Longitude_MIN <= v_lng and 
                      mv.Latitude_MAX >=  v_lat and  
                      mv.Latitude_MIN <= v_lat  and  
                      STR_TO_DATE(mv.Date, '%m/%d/%Y') = v_date
                      -- limit 1
                      and mt.pkid = v_pkid;
END LOOP get_update;

CLOSE weather_cursor;
commit;  

END;
```

in both tables, there are Primary keys, in "mytable" 187000 records while in "myvalues" 1000000 records. the task is to merge the data in "mytable".

In about 3 hours it updated only 3000 records.

how to optimize this update so the procedure run quickly?

in reference to gordon answer, I have the following update statement:

```
UPDATE mytable mt INNER JOIN
   myvalues mv
   ON mt.accident_dt = mv.date and
      mt.pkid = v_pkid 
SET mt.tmax = mv.tmax, mt.tmin = mv.tmin, mt.dayl= mv.dayl ,
    mt.prcp = mv.prcp , mt.srad = mv.srad, mt.swe=mv.swe, mt.vp=mv.vp
WHERE mv.Longitude_MAX >= v_lng and 
      mv.Longitude_MIN <= v_lng and 
      mv.Latitude_MAX >=  v_lat and  
      mv.Latitude_MIN <= v_lat;
```

(i) I have modified the data type of mv.date to date.
(ii) created indexes on mv.date and mt.accident_dt columns

Now the update records per minute increased from 15 to 52.
Is there any change I need to make in this update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are looping for the update, this probably doesn't have a big impact on performance.  Probably the key problem is:

```
ON STR_TO_DATE(mv.Date, '%m/%d/%Y') = mt.accident_dt
```

This requires scanning through the entire `mv` table for each value.  I would suggest that you modify the table so the `Date` column is actually stored as a date/time value.  Then you can build an index on it.

An alternative is to use the variable `v_date`.  If I assume that `mv.Date` has no time component, then I can write the query like this:

```
UPDATE mytable mt INNER JOIN
       myvalues mv
       ON mt.accident_dt = v_date and
          mt.pkid = v_pkid and
          mv.Date = DATE_FORMAT(v_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
    SET mt.tmax = mv.tmax, mt.tmin = mv.tmin, mt.dayl= mv.dayl ,
        mt.prcp = mv.prcp , mt.srad = mv.srad, mt.swe=mv.swe, mt.vp=mv.vp
    WHERE mv.Longitude_MAX >= v_lng and 
          mv.Longitude_MIN <= v_lng and 
          mv.Latitude_MAX >=  v_lat and  
          mv.Latitude_MIN <= v_lat;
```

With this structure, an index on `myvalues(date, Longitude_Max)` should help.  I'm not sure why you need two conditions on `mt` if one of them is one the primary key.  If `pkid` is not a primary key, then you should have an index on mytable(accident_dt, pkid)` as well.

EDIOT:

I would suggest that rename the old column, add another column with the same name, and then update the values:

```
alter table myvalues change column date oldDate varchar(255);

alter table myvalues add column date date;

update myvalues
    set date = ON STR_TO_DATE(oldDate, '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Comment: the pkid is primary key. how can i modify the date column to datatype date from varchar, I tried but it convert the data to wrong date. 1/1/2000 to 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Comment: thanks your query bring some change in time, the old query require 0:00:43.836 and new 0:00:26.619, can you guide me how to convert the varchar to date so the data ( date ) don't destroy, like the one is done in my last comments.

Comment: this solution for some 1 million records updation is good, compare to the above one, which don't use the cursor. in my case ( with poor resources / hardware ), because I could not see how many records are updated? my computer was running for 2 days but no result. so I used the cursor and put a commit on the end of procedure. also I used some amount of records between some dates so can check after running the procedure how many records are updated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bit late in the game, and although I agree with the suggestions proposed by @Gordon Linoff, I did get confused as to why you need to the cursor in your stored procedure ?

Is the `mytable` used in the cursor the same `mytable` in the UPDATE ?

If so you should get rid of the cursor entirely and 'reduce' the stored procedure to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `task_51_proce`()
BEGIN


UPDATE mytable mt 
INNER JOIN myvalues mv
   ON mt.accident_dt = mv.date   
  SET mt.tmax = mv.tmax, mt.tmin = mv.tmin, mt.dayl= mv.dayl ,
      mt.prcp = mv.prcp , mt.srad = mv.srad, mt.swe=mv.swe, mt.vp=mv.vp
WHERE mv.Longitude_MAX >= mt.lng and 
      mv.Longitude_MIN <= mt.lng and 
      mv.Latitude_MAX >= mt.lat and  
      mv.Latitude_MIN <= mt.lat;

commit;  

END;
```

As far as I can tell, this would update the entire range in 1 single operation. Depending on the amount of data involved it could take a while; but it surely will be faster than trying to do it row by row.

Comment: can I put where mt.tmax is null in where, that it update only null records?

Comment: I need to update these values in the top 1 row, I think the above update don't update in single row, some field from different rows.

Comment: Well, I couldn't deduce that from your original query (I guess that's where the commented `-- limit 1` came from ?)
Anyway, even then I'm pretty sure you can get rid of the cursor, but I guess you'll need to split the work in 2 steps. How do you know which record is 'the right one' from the myvalues table ? (biggest this, smallest that, some top row based on some ORDER BY ?)